# Rename a ForeignKey in models.py

Tags: python, django, rename, models

I created a models.py looking this way:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    zip = models.IntegerField("Postleitzahl") 
    place = models.CharField("Ort", max_length=32)
    customer_number = models.CharField("Kundennummer", max_length=32) 
    bank = models.ForeignKey("Bank", Bank)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.first_name) + ' ' + unicode(self.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/customers/detail/%i" % self.id
```

Now i would like to "rename" my attributes in the model. For example, i want to display the word "Postleitzahl" instead of zip. This works really good, but when i tried to "rename" the ForeignKey bank, my manage.py isn't able to run the server.

Does anyone know, how to rename a ForeignKey?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `verbose_name` argument to it:

```
bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, verbose_name="Bank")
```

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names):

> Each field type, except for ForeignKey, ManyToManyField and
>   OneToOneField, takes an optional first positional argument – a verbose
>   name. If the verbose name isn’t given, Django will automatically
>   create it using the field’s attribute name, converting underscores to
>   spaces.
>
> **ForeignKey, ManyToManyField and OneToOneField require the first
>   argument to be a model class, so use the verbose_name keyword argument**